# Is it possible to embed conditional actions into barcode

Tags: mobile, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I would like to know if it possible to create a barcode that contains conditional logic.

```
if (x == true) 
   do this
else 
   do that
```

The context would be someone using the camera on their mobile device to `scan` a barcode.

Taking the pseudo-code from above and applying it to my particular use case the scenario becomes:

```
if (mobile device has particular mobile app installed and active session is detected)
    open mobile app to particular module and update something

else if (mobile device has particular mobile app installed and no active session is detected)
    prompt user to authenticate, followed by opening module and updating something

else 
   prompt user to download and install mobile app
```

A)  Is this possible?

B)  If yes, is there a particular set of barcode types (e.g. 1D and/or 2D barcodes) that would need to be used in order to achieve this?

C)  Is there a limitation to any particular mobile device that could do this (e.g. platform dependence)?

Comment: Barcodes are just data, not CPUs or programs. What you want to do needs to be done in the program that handles the barcode, not in the barcode.

Comment: @kunif - Thanks for setting my thought process straight here.